# Getting error message trying to use defined functions for simple equation

Tags: python, python-3.x

My professor is requiring us to define our own functions for a simple problem and it's proving troublesome. Here's my code:

Create two functions: one to have a user input hours parked, and another to calculate the parking fee

```
def getParkingHours():

    input('Enter hours parked:'))
    return ' '

x=print(getParkingHours())

def calcParkingFee(hours):

    fee=hours*2.5
    return fee

print(calcParkingFee(x))
```

I'm getting the error message: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'float'`

Why am I getting this error message?

Comment: `getParkingHours` returns `' '` and not your input. With `x=print(getParkingHours())` `x` will get the return value from `print` and that's always `None`.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are trying to return input value instead of nothing i.e. `None`.

```
def getParkingHours():
    return float(input('Enter hours parked:\n'))

def calcParkingFee(hours):
    fee=hours*2.5
    return fee

x=getParkingHours()
print(calcParkingFee(x))
```

Seeing your requirement, I have modified it as below:

```
def getParkingHours():
    userInput = input('Enter hours parked:\n')
    if userInput.isdigit():
        return float(userInput)
    else:
        return 0
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could add an explanation.

Comment: Ah okay thanks! I also want the program to return a 'None' if the user inputs anything other than an integer...is that something I would put under the first function im defining

Comment: I have modified the post, please check

Answer (score 0):

You are not retrieving the user input in your function. `input` returns the string entered by the user, so you need to return that. It also seems that you're expecting an int, so you will have to cast that string to int.

```
def getParkingHours():
    user_input = input("Enter input")
    return int(user_input)
```